Accessing elements from webpage using Chrome developer tool
I am facing an unusual issue accessing web element inside a web page. When I try to inspect second time only using chrome devtool I am able to view the element which is under a iframe that i need to access.
But the first time I inspect I don't see the iframe but there are other iframes which is not relevant to me.
I tried to display the iframe elements using selenium java code. However, I don't see the specific iframe which I need to switch to and access the web element.
I tried to forcibly switch with the iframe name, it fails as the iframe is not found. I have given enough sleep time and implicit wait so that the web page is fully loaded, with no much help.
I tried to print the elements from seleinium java code. But it doesn't display the iframe I require. Hence I cannot switch to the iframe.

Without your code, and probably the page you are accessing, it's not really possibly to offer any meaningful help.

Apparently, it's my companies website. So will have a compliance issue. But, I would like to know as to why do I need to inspect the element twice to see on the dev tool. Is it because of a page is being loaded the second time I inspect which exposes the iframe and the elements within it?

Ask whoever maintains your site? They might be able to provide direct access to whatever you are trying to scrape too?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Update: I was able to resolve the issue. While i was inspecting the web page with chrome browser via dev tool i am able to traverse to the element with just one click inspect. However, while using Chrome browser launched by Selenium, it wasnt exposing the element on first click, rather on second click.   I found out that the iframe, and elements were under "#shadow-root(open). Inorder to resolved this i used Shadow class to access the element in the below way

static Shadow shadow; shadow = new Shadow(driver);WebElement parent_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//mfl[@componentname="Deposit"]"));
WebElement iframe_mobile = shadow.findElementByXPath(parent_element, "//[@id='legacy-widget']");
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe_mobile);
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id="tab-1"]/div/table"));

If you've solved your issue, you should post your solution as an answer and not a comment.
